# Inline div with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's say I have 2 div that should be inline and I want to make the second div grow below the first div if the content is more than parent div.  now when I add `flex` and make them inline, it looks like this :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/xd04o5nc/1/)

Something like this:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: `.field { flex: 1 0 auto; }`

Comment: Thanks, but it makes it horizontally

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a content div(second div) grow in the bottom of the first div

Comment: like this? .group-title-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

Comment: @Sfili_81 no, please see my updated, added a picture

Comment: ok remove display:flex and add : .group-title-wrapper{

}
.field-name-post-date{
  float:left;  
  width:auto;  
} This is my first idea.

Comment: thank you very much, any idea with flex ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think you can't with flex.

Comment: Thanks a million for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with flexbox.

However, if you make the required elements `display:inline` it is.

```css
.field,
.field-items,
.field-item {
  display: inline;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-title-wrapper">
  <div class="field field-name-post-date field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">08 January</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even" property="dc:title">
        <h2>Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.Lorem ipsum dolor amet schlitz ennui taxidermy bespoke vinyl lyft iceland selfies quinoa intelligentsia. Tacos semiotics yuccie fam photo booth hella health goth kitsch whatever waistcoat.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.